# UITableView Cells get reordered after editing the cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my app, You can tap a cell, and it brings up a new view. You can edit the tableviewCell's textLabel, and save it. But when you switch views and come back to the tableView, the cells are in a different order. What could be the reason for this?

Here is my Code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString * identifier = @"identifier";

self.cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

h = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *brandModel = [[h.brand stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:h.model];

self.cell.mainLabel.text = brandModel;

self.cell.nicknameLabel.text = handguns.nickname;   

return self.cell;
}
```

Comment: the key piece of code is missing. what does your code to do modify the tableArray when the user changes something? I'm going to speculate it reorders the array at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are reloading tableView after saving UITableView cell then It will be reordered as initial because array from which you are setting cell data is as it is.You can change only table View cells not array data position in an array.

Below I have written a UITableView code to move cells and it is working fine after pushing view.If I **remove reload method** from viewWillAppear:

```
#import "MoveCellViewController.h"

@interface MoveCellViewController ()

@end

@implementation MoveCellViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 UIBarButtonItem *left=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(edit)];
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=left;

 myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];  //mutable array;
 myArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Aman",@"Ankit",@"Sumit",@"Hercules",@"Jackie Chan", nil];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)edit
{
 if (self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title==@"Edit") {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title=@"Done";
    [_tableView setEditing:YES];
 }else
 {
  [_tableView setEditing:NO];
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title=@"Edit";
 }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return [myArray count];
}
// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cellIdentifier";
 UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

 if (cell==nil) {
  cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
 }

 cell.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
 cell.textLabel.text=[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath{
 id ob = [myArray objectAtIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

 [myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:destinationIndexPath.row withObject:[myArray objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row]];
 [myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row withObject:ob];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 NextViewController *nx=[[NextViewController alloc] init];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:nx animated:YES];
}
@end
```

This is working code and will not change after push view controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

     cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


     if (cell == nil)
     {
    
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2     reuseIdentifier:nil];
     }

     Write rest of the code here
}
```

Comment: thanks or the reply, however i can't use the UITableViewCellStyleValue2 because im using a custom UITableView Cell!

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; 
   }
h = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *brandModel = [[h.brand stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:h.model];

self.cell.mainLabel.text = brandModel;

self.cell.nicknameLabel.text = handguns.nickname;   

return self.cell;
}
```